# How to keep AdSense Ads with AdBlock for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, adblock

How can I stop AdBlock from removing AdSense? Important: AdSense is NOT the ads you get when you search on Google. AdSense ads are the ads you get on 3rd party websites who make money with it.

Edit: The reason is that AdSense is about the only useful form of advertising on the internet. Because you have to pay money to get into it it serves as a nice spam filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure none of the following are part of the block list:

```
http://partner.googleadservices.com/
http://www.google-analytics.com/
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/
doubleclick.net
```

Also be on the lookout for rules that may indirectly affect those. Rules such as:

```
|http://pagead2.*
```

Comment: How do I get these elements ignored? I saw they are in the standard 2 blocklists which I obviously cannot remove. I entered in the options dialog the following "filters":

h ttp://partner.googleadservices.com/
h ttp://www.google-analytics.com/
h ttp://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/
*doubleclick .net*
|h ttp://pagead2.*
h ttp://pagead2.*

They do not work however. Is this even the right approach?

Comment: PS: I added spaces because I could not get the formatting right. The text was made into links.

Comment: You cannot use standard blocklists for this. You may copy their contents into the "Add your Own Filters" tab, edit them as you please from there, and remove any standard blocklist.

Comment: Ok. It works but it is not a pretty solution because I will be missing updates. I will wait for a week to see if someone has a better idea, and, if not, accept your answer.